# Why would a UART only transmit the first character and then stop?

Tags: microcontroller, stm32, embedded, uart, transmitter

For some context I'm using a STM32H7A3 chip: [reference manual](https://www.st.com/resource/en/reference_manual/rm0455-stm32h7a37b3-and-stm32h7b0-value-line-advanced-armbased-32bit-mcus-stmicroelectronics.pdf)

With this UART and pin configuration:

```
GPIOB.OSPEEDR.OSPEED9 = 0b10

// usart_ker_ck_pres(8MHz) = usart_ker_ck(64MHz) / PRESCALER(8)
UART4.PRESC.PRESCALER = 0b0100

// 1 start bit, 8 data bits
UART4.CR1.M0 = 0
UART4.CR1.M1 = 0

// baud(9600) = usart_ker_ck_pres(8MHz) / USARTDIV(833)
UART4.BRR.BRR = 0x0341

// 1 stop bit
UART4.CR2.STOP = 0

// Enable UART
UART4.CR1.UE = 1
// Enable transmit
UART4.CR1.TE = 1
```

in addition to the relevant clocks enabled and pin alternative function.

Now sending a string of characters by waiting for `UART4.ISR.TXE` and writing to `UART4.TDR` for each character results in only the first character being actually sent. In pseudocode:

```
function transmit(message) {
  for byte in message {
    while UART4.ISR.TXE == 0 {
      // wait
    }
    UART4.TDR.TDR = byte
  }
}
```

What might be a hint is that if I wait for some time after sending each character, it works, but obviously it's slower. Essentially sending a "first character" repeatedly:

```
function transmit(message) {
  for byte in message {
    while UART4.ISR.TXE == 0 {
      // wait
    }
    UART4.TDR.TDR = byte
    delay(100000)
  }
}
```

A possibly relevant piece of additional information is that I'm using an arduino UNO with RST connected to GND as a serial to USB converter, and I'm using arduino-cli to monitor the serial connection on my pc.

Comment: You might want to show the full code, not pseudocode. And also how UART4 with TXE and ISR are defined. The pseudocode looks fine. The problem is not in the pseudocode.

Comment: Aha, you said you can only send first letter, and I believed you. What if there is nothing wrong with your sending code, but the parts that you use to receive and print the result? Which Arduino UNO is it? Which USB to UART chipset it uses? Which IO supply voltage it uses for UART?

Comment: I'd rather not post the full code because it includes 80k LOC of auto-generated register access code.

It's Arduino UNO R3, it's using the supply voltage over USB from the PC.

Comment: Maybe your code is not compiled to use volatile access to the flag. I would use a volatile local pointer to the bit.

Comment: @Justme it looks like it uses the Atmega16u2 for serial. Maybe I should just get a usb to serial converter to eliminate this problem vector.

Comment: @ElectronicsStudent, the register access does use volatile. Everything else works fine and does register access in the same way. And I've triple checked the values for UART4 ISR and TXE

Comment: You are transmitting  the characters back-to-back wit a single stop bit. Check the receiving side stop bit settings that these match, and it doesn't have 1.5 stop bits or something. Even if it has 1 stop bit, it might be quite sensitive to small timing mismatches, so try to change both sides (or just the transmitting side) to 1.5 stop bits.

Comment: @EugeneSh. I tried a bunch of different combinations of baudrate and stop bits at both ends, the result is always the same. Is it possible that the clock on my MCU is not accurate enough?

Comment: It is unlikely that the oscillator is that much off, but it might be the case that your baud rate is not exact. Have you calculated it to be exact or with some error?

Comment: @EugeneSh. The datasheet claims the HSI clock runs at 64MHz, I divide it by 8 and then again by 833 which gives a baud rate of 9603.84. I think that should be close enough. And if I change it significantly it stops working for even the first character.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely the code is fine, and the problems are receiving the data in hardware or software.

You are using a 5V Arduino with Atmega16U2 as the USB to serial adapter for a (likely) 3.3V signal. It should work but not all STM32 pins are 5V tolerant and it might cause the Atmega16U2 to output excessive current trying to push 5V into STM32 which tries to clamp the overvoltage with internal protection diodes to supply.

You would be far better off with a USB to serial adapter with IO voltage that matches the STM32 supply, and trying another terminal program.

But it is still possible the problem is in the code. You have a completely custom framework nobody knows anything about, auto-generating some register access code, and you are posting only pseudocode.

There is just too many variables and you need to eliminate things one by one, for example by verifying with an oscilloscope or logic analyzer if there really is only one byte coming out, or debug the code by stepping it through.

Comment: These particular pins are 5V tolerant according to the datasheet. Unfortunately I don't have an oscilloscope, but just knowing there's nothing wrong with this pseudocode and I'm not misunderstanding how the UART is supposed to be used is already helpful so I'll accept this answer.

Comment: @ultraturbonoob "Unfortunately I don't have an oscilloscope" Then you either need to get one or hand the project over to embedded system programmers. If you are still in school I'm sure there are scopes you can get access to. It's a mandatory tool, just as essential as an in-circuit debugger.